# Facebook og:image does not work

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am still trying to get a thumbnail as preview when sharing this site on facebook:

http://hundeschule-olching.de/

I have added the following code to my header:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=3d2bee-1459359037.jpg" />
```

I needed to load that image up first, even though it already is posted on facebook, but for some reason facebook does not accept its own links.

This would be the original facebook link:

https://www.facebook.com/202405526459834/photos/pb.202405526459834.-2207520000.1459358633./1184106678289709/?type=3&theater

It was already showing me the correct image in the debug tool from facebook, but when i tried to post the link in facebook, a completely different image was shown..(pick option).
After running the debugger again the image that was fetched correctly a few minutes before was gone and it told me there will be a selection shown to pick from.

So I tried to fetch the image from the Data folder on the server going like this:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="Data/chak.jpg" />
```

did not work as well.

Please help me I'm going crazy about this problem.

Comment: `http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=3d2bee-1459359037.jpg` does not deliver an image, but an HTML document – at least for me. It is probably some sort of hotlinking protection of that upload service at work. You should test this with an image on a server you have control over, to avoid such problems. And you need to use an absolute URL – a relative one like `Data/chak.jpg` won’t work either.

Comment: well you helped me solve the problem... I am now using an image that is already on my server, referring to it via the url you get shown when you click it.
It really was as simple as that.... I'm sorry that I can't mark your comment as answer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, let me add it as an answer then, if it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=3d2bee-1459359037.jpg` does not deliver an image, but an HTML document – at least for me. It is probably some sort of hotlinking protection of that upload service at work. You should test this with an image on a server you have control over, to avoid such problems.

And you need to use an absolute URL – a relative one like `Data/chak.jpg` won’t work either.